# Build directory tree from dropbox API

Tags: python, dropbox

What I'd like to do is to build a tree from the dropbox API, for a given path, with share links for each path, using the python bindings.

My proposed structure looks something like this:

```
[
    {
        'path': '/a',
        'is_dir': True,
        'contents': [
            {
                'path': '/a/b',
                'is_dir': True,
                'contents': [etc]
            },
            {
                'path': '/a/readme.txt',
                'is_dir': False,
                'share_link': 'http://etc'
            }
        ]
    },
    etc.
]
```

I've got something that mostly works using `metadata()` but it's hideously slow as it needs to make an API call per directory traversed.

What I'd like to use instead is `delta()`, which will get me every file in one request, then build it into a tree, but I'm having problems figuring out exactly how, in particular how to parse the paths into a tree.

Edit: And I've realised there's a call for each share link so I'm going to omit those and just get them when requested.

Here's some code I have to get the data I need so far:

```
paths = []

for path, metadata in client.delta(path_prefix='/whatever')['entries']:
    paths.append({
        'path': path,
        'is_dir': metadata['is_dir']
    })
```

So I guess I'm having trouble figuring out how to get those paths nested. Pretty sure I need a recursive function here but can't quite figure it out.

Comment: The HTTP docs for /delta have some more information about the returned data: https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/docs#delta And this blog post, though in Python, may be of some use: https://blogs.dropbox.com/developers/2013/12/efficiently-enumerating-dropbox-with-delta/

Comment: `/delta` is definitely the way to enumerate the files, but you'll still need to create a share link for each file, right? That's going to be the slow part.

Comment: I guess you guys have missed the python tag so I'll edit to make that more clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tweaked your structure just a bit... here's the JSON representation of what the below code produces. Note that I've made the contents field a dictionary indexed by path instead of an array. This is just a little easier and makes for more efficient lookup, but it should be pretty easy to convert to exactly what you have above if you want:

```
{
    "is_dir": true,
    "contents": {
        "/foo.txt": {
            "is_dir": false,
            "contents": {}
        },
        "/a": {
            "is_dir": true,
            "contents": {
                "/a/bar.txt": {
                    "is_dir": false,
                    "contents": {}
                },
                "/a/b": {
                    "is_dir": true,
                    "contents": {
                        "/a/b/hello.txt": {
                            "is_dir": false,
                            "contents": {}
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the code that produces that output:

```
ACCESS_TOKEN = '<REDACTED>'

from collections import defaultdict
import json

from dropbox.client import DropboxClient

def make_tree():
    return {
        'is_dir': True,
        'contents': defaultdict(make_tree)
    }
tree = defaultdict(make_tree)

client = DropboxClient(ACCESS_TOKEN)

has_more = True
cursor = None

while has_more:
    delta = client.delta(cursor)

    cursor = delta['cursor']
    has_more = delta['has_more']

    for path, metadata in delta['entries']:
        if metadata is not None:

            # find the right place in the tree
            segments = path.split('/')
            location = tree['/']
            for i in xrange(1, len(segments)-1):
                current_path = '/'.join(segments[:i+1])
                location = location['contents'][current_path]

            # insert the new entry
            location['contents'][path] = {
                'is_dir': metadata['is_dir'],
                'contents': {}
            }

print json.dumps(tree['/'], indent=4)
```

Comment: Thanks! This almost works perfectly, but one thing - if I call `delta()` with a prefix, like `delta(cursor, '/a/prefix')`, `/` is still at the root of the tree. I can  change it to the prefix I specify, but then under `/a/prefix` is another redundant `/a/prefix`. Any ideas?

Comment: No need to get tricky there... it sounds like a single `if` statement could probably solve that. :-)

Comment: Now that I think about it, that's not quite the issue. The problem is, if I specify a prefix, `/a/prefix` it currently shows `/a` and `/a/prefix` though I'm not getting the files from them. Really, if I specify a prefix, I'd like that prefix to be the root and not display anything above it.

Comment: And I guess I solved it by replacing the path prefix with an empty string in the for loop but it seems a bit messy.