# Django template tag to recurse a nested dict

Tags: python, django

This is a followup on [Build directory tree from dropbox API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31485418/build-directory-tree-from-dropbox-api/)

I've got my dictionary sorted out, and it's how I want it. But now I'd like to write a template tag that writes this nested structure out as html, something like:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        Dir/
        <ul>
            <li>
                Dir2/
                ...
            </li>
            <li>Inner File</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>File1</li>
    <li>File2</li>
</ul>
```

All I've been able to come up with is a recursive generator that gets me the files and directories and I can put these in a flat list just fine, but I can't figure out how to get the nesting to work, and how to get the html in the right place.

```
def recurse(d):
    for key, value in d.items():
        if value['contents']:
            for inner_key, inner_value in recurse(value['contents']):
                yield inner_key, inner_value
        else:
            yield key, value
```

And the template tag:

```
@register.simple_tag()
def dropbox_files():
    files = function_from_other_question()

    s = '<ul>'
    for key, value in recurse(files):
        s += '<li>{}</li>'.format(key)
    s += '</ul>'
    return s
```

This gets me all the paths, but as I said, without any nested structure.

Comment: Can you include the code that you've written so far?

Comment: @mfcovington Sure, it's done.

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to do with a template include:

recurse_dict.html

```
{% if dict and dict.keys|length > 0 %}
<ul>
    {% for key, value in dict.items %}
        <li>
            {% if value and value.keys|length > 0 %}
               {{ key }} {% include "recurse_dict.html" with dict=value %}
            {% else %}
               {{ value }}
            {% endif %}
        </li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
{% endif %}
```